# Conditional assignment inside logical operation

Tags: java, coding-style

Is this shorthand a bad practice or should any programmer with basic knowledge of Java know that in the code below `checkDoSResult` doesn't get reassigned if `host` equals to `"localhost"`?

```
int checkDoSResult = 0;
if (!"localhost".equals(host) && (checkDoSResult = CheckHost.checkDoS(user+"@"+host, "query"))!=0)
...
```

Comment: This is bad practice. It's easy to understand what's going on, but it's definitely harder to read when you write it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that "any programmer with basic knowledge of Java" knows something does not necessarily make that "something" a good practice.

Assignments inside conditions and loop headers are notoriously hard to spot, because programmer's eye is expecting a condition there, not an assignment. Placing the assignment in a short-circuited section of the logical expression only makes things worse.

Of course, any programmer with decent training would be able to "decipher" exactly what you wanted to say, but it would take them time. Splitting the condition into two parts, and placing the assignment inside the body of your `if` statement, will help others understand your intention, which is more important than saving a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this:

```
int checkDoSResult = 0;
if (!"localhost".equals(host) && (checkDoSResult = CheckHost.checkDoS(user+"@"+host, "query"))!=0) {
    ...
}
```

Or this (@Arkantos) :

```
int checkDoSResult = 0;
if (!"localhost".equals(host)) {
    checkDoSResult = CheckHost.checkDoS(user+"@"+host, "query");
    if (checkDoSResult != 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Both snippets do the same, but which one is easier to read? I'd go with the second option.

Comment: I think second if condition `checkDoSResult != 0` should go inside the first one after re-assigning

Comment: It doesn't really matter since `checkDoSResult` will only be different than zero if the first `if` was true. But I'll edit anyway, it kinda makes more sense the way you say.

Comment: I'll actually keep both versions. I like when I can avoid another indentation level :)

Comment: It's not just about indentation :) According to OP's code, there's an `&` operator which means second condition will be evaluated only if the first one is true. That's why I asked you to move the second if condition inside otherwise the second if condition is always evaluated

Comment: True story. Since the second `if` condition has no collateral effects, it doesn't really matter. But you're totally right: the second condition is, in fact, being unnecessarily evaluated.